# How do I crawl ajax website using Apache Nutch

Tags: nutch

I want to crawl this site: https://511.org/alerts/traffic/incidents using Apache Nutch. The webpage has dynamically loaded ajax content. If I crawl it with the default configurations, Nutch just brings headers and footers and dynamically loaded content is lost. I am using Nutch 1.14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Nutch 1.14, you can use either the [Nutch Selenium](https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/a8e60bdfb79b368612f068ed5aeeb690e29b448d/src/plugin/protocol-selenium) or the [Nutch Interactive Selenium](https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/a8e60bdfb79b368612f068ed5aeeb690e29b448d/src/plugin/protocol-interactiveselenium) plugins to crawl pages with dynamically loaded elements.

Comment: Tried using protocol-selenium. In fetch stage, I get the following error:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin) on port 7055; process output follows: 
null
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09 13:08:06'
System info: host: '<my-host>', ip: '<my-ip>', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.2', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver`

Comment: Could not get it to work with Firefox. Working fine with Chrome and Phantomjs.